# using fgets with structure

Tags: c, structure, fgets

I am trying to use `fgets` with structure, since I have to insert in character array. But when I use fgets it's not working properly. I can not enter value for the char array. Please help. Below is a sample program::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Student
{
    int roll;
    char name[50];
    int age;
    char branch[50];    
    char gender[1]; //F for female and M for male
};

int main()
{
    struct Student s1;
    
    printf("enter roll number of the student: ");
    scanf("%d", &s1.roll);
    
    printf("Enter student name: ");
    fgets(s1.name, 50, stdin);  // NOT WORKING ...
    
    printf("Enter age number: ");
    scanf("%d", &s1.age);
    
    printf("Enter branch number: ");
    scanf("%d", &s1.branch);
    
    printf("Enter Gender: ");
    scanf("%d", &s1.gender);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide example(s), of both what you want to happen and what is happening.  And why can't you use the same technique for `name` as you do for `brach` and `gender`?

Comment: You are mixing formatted input (`scanf`) with line-wise input (`fgets`). After reading the roll number, the "return" that you entered was not read. Intractive input (prompt: input; prompt: input) is a bit tricky with C. A two-step approach could work: Read every input line with `fgets`, then parse it with `sscanf`.

Comment: "it's not working properly" is not a problem description. Explain exactly what you think should happen, and explain what happens instead and why that's wrong.

Comment: For `name` I have to insert `space character` too, so I used `fgets`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need different format specifiers for different datatypes. So you need to use `%c` for a character and `%[^\n]` for a string containing spaces.

You also need to remove leading [whitespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) before scanning a string, because a newline `\n` is left in the input buffer which would otherwise be read by `%c` and `%[]`, as [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924) pointed out in a comment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student
{
    int roll;
    char name[50];
    int age;
    char branch[50];
    char gender; // can be a single character
};

int main(void)
{
    struct student s1;

    printf("Enter roll number: ");
    scanf("%d", &s1.roll);

    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf(" %49[^\n]", s1.name); // use %[^\n] to scan a string containing spaces

    printf("Enter age: ");
    scanf("%d", &s1.age);

    printf("Enter branch name: ");
    scanf(" %49[^\n]", s1.branch);

    printf("Enter gender: ");
    scanf(" %c", &s1.gender); // %c is the format specifier for a char

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: with `scanf` how can I input space character for name?

Comment: @nischalinn By using the `[^\n]` specifier instead of the `%s` specifier.

Comment: Note that in another answer the spaces which sometimes appear before `%` are significant and necessary. Most of the format specifiers for `scanf` automatically filter leading whitespace, but `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not. Adding a space in front of the `%` instructs `scanf` to filter leading whitespace here too. Otherwise you are back at square one: a newline is left in the buffer which is read by `%c` or `%[]`.

Comment: Re edit: using `getchar()` to remove whitespace is a horrible kludge which is quite unnecessary, since `scanf` provides the mechanism to do that neatly. It's better to understand how `scanf` handles whitespace. If you really need to clear an input buffer (for example there is input which cannot be processed) it's better to start with `fgets()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have now updated my answer to implement your suggested improvements.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` is not being bypassed, it's actually working as it should, what happens is that it reads the newline character that remains in the input buffer from the previous `scanf`, if you access `s1.name` you will see that it has a string (`"\n\0"`) in it.

> *For name I have to insert space character too, so I used `fgets`*

You can use `scanf` with `[^\n]` specifier which can read spaces. Mixing `scanf` with `fgets` is trouble, it can be done, but you should avoid it.

You should either use `scanf` only, or `fgets` only, in the latter case, if you need to convert strings to `int`s use `sscanf` or better yet `strtol`.

Your code has other issues, detailed in the comments with corrections:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

```
struct Student
{
    int roll;
    char name[50];
    int age;
    char branch[50];
    char gender; //F for female and M for male
};
```

For  solution with `scanf` only it should, more or less, look like this:

```
void clear_buffer(){ // helper function to clear buffer
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){}
    if(c == EOF){ 
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error!"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

```
int main()
{
    struct Student s1;

    printf("enter roll number of the student: ");
    while (scanf("%d", &s1.roll) != 1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Bad input, try again: ");
        clear_buffer();
    }    // if bad input ask again

    printf("Enter student name: ");                 // the space before % clears blanks
    while (scanf(" %49[^\n]", s1.name) != 1){       // will read the line until 
        fprintf(stderr, "Bad input, try again: ");  // enter is pressed, provided 
        clear_buffer();                             // that it's not larger than 49
    }                                              
      
    printf("Enter age number: ");
    while(scanf("%d", &s1.age) != 1){  
        fprintf(stderr, "Bad input, try again: ");
        clear_buffer();
    }

    printf("Enter branch number: ");
    while (scanf(" %49[^\n]", s1.branch) != 1){    // branch is a string, %d
        clear_buffer();                            // specifier is for ints.
        fprintf(stderr, "Bad input, try again: "); // note that I'm using width
    }                                              // limit (49) to avoid buffer overflow  
                                                 
    printf("Enter Gender: ");                                          
    while(scanf(" %c", &s1.gender) != 1){          // only 1 character needed, use %c
        fprintf(stderr, "Bad input, try again: ");
        clear_buffer();  
    } 
}
```

---

For a solution with `fgets` only which, I would argue is better, you can do something like this:

```
int main(){
    struct Student s1;
    char temp[50];

    printf("enter roll number of the student: ");
    if (fgets(temp, sizeof temp, stdin)){
        if (sscanf(temp, "%d", &s1.roll) != 1){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing input!\n");
        }
    }
    printf("Enter student name: ");
    if (fgets(temp, sizeof temp, stdin)){
        if (sscanf(temp, "%49[^\n]", s1.name) != 1){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing input!\n");
        }
    }
    printf("Enter age number: ");
    if (fgets(temp, sizeof temp, stdin)){
        if (sscanf(temp, "%d", &s1.age) != 1){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing input!\n");
        }
    }
    printf("Enter branch number: ");
    if (fgets(temp, sizeof temp, stdin)){
        if (sscanf(temp, "%49[^\n]", s1.branch) != 1){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing input!\n");
        }
    }
    printf("Enter Gender: ");
    if (fgets(temp, sizeof temp, stdin)){
        if (sscanf(temp, " %c", &s1.gender) != 1){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing input!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

`*scanf` to parse `int`s still  has a potencial flaw in case of overflow, there is no way of guarding against that, unless you use a more robust method like the aforementioned `strtol`.

Comment: If `scanf("%d", &s1.roll)` etc fail, repeating it will keep on failing.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, on to that

Comment: @WeatherVane, not bullet proof, but fixed.

Comment: Seems to fix it but I hate such `getchar()` kludges. `fgets()` rocks...

Comment: @WeatherVane, indeed.

Comment: Why are you only reading 49 characters `%49[^\n]` when the string is of length 50 `char name[50]`?

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang, the last space is for the null byte `\0`.